# Convert split APKs to aab

Tags: android, apk, adb

I want to convert split APKs into a single universal APK. However, there seems to be no direct way for it. 
I have found a way to install split APKs via `adb install-multiple` and `bundletool` to convert aab file to a single universal apk via `--mode=universal`.

I need the single apk so that I can distribute and share the APPs available on PlayStore to other people.
The reason I want to do this conversion is because usually I obtain and test the split APKs from website like [www.apkpure.com](https://www.apkpure.com)

Just to make the question clear: I would like to test the app from the PlayStore and not having the source code myself.

Answer (score -1):

What is the point of merging the split apks from the Android app bundle, which has more potential of error and where you will often miss an asset.

Instead, you can distribute your app as an android app bundle and generate an .apk locally for whatever reason you want the complete apk.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for that and I would like to test app from playstore, not generating it by myself.

Comment: Well, the point of converting it to an apk means that there is no missing asset, and that people can install it without getting an app to install split apks. It's much easier to deal with apks than split apks.